# How can I create a dictionary from a list where the keys are the indexes and the values are the actual elements of the list one by one?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to initialize a dictionary to start a clustering model of the elements I have in a list, and when I'll do the clusters I will merge the elements by their indices, but then I need to display the strings that I have in the list. So I thought about doing a dictionary and merge the values every time I cluster them.

So let's say that I have the following list:

```
fileList = ["doc1", "doc2", "doc3", "doc4", "doc5"]
```

My idea is to create a dictionary out of them with indices as keys and the strings as values:

```
fileDict = {0: ["doc1"], 1: ["doc2"], 2: ["doc3"], 3: ["doc4"], 4: ["doc5"]}
```

And then after the clustering process, I can change the names of the keys and print:

```
clustersDict = {1: ["doc1", "doc2", "doc3"], 2: ["doc4", "doc5"]}
```

Now, what I tried was this:

```
 clustersDict = dict.fromkeys([i for i in range(len(listFiles)), name for name in listFiles])
```

And the problem is that to every key it attaches the whole list of files, not just one, I tried with the index I but it obviously says that it's not defined, and I don't really know how to move on since I'm pretty new to Python.

Thank you!

Comment: Remember to format your code before submitting any question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fileList = ["doc1", "doc2", "doc3", "doc4", "doc5"]
{v:[k] for v, k in enumerate(fileList)}
```

result:

```
{0: ['doc1'], 1: ['doc2'], 2: ['doc3'], 3: ['doc4'], 4: ['doc5']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
fileList = ["doc1", "doc2", "doc3", "doc4", "doc5"]

result = dict(enumerate([f] for f in fileList))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{0: ['doc1'], 1: ['doc2'], 2: ['doc3'], 3: ['doc4'], 4: ['doc5']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dict comprehension

```py
fileList = ["doc1", "doc2", "doc3", "doc4", "doc5"]
filedict = {idx:val for idx,val in enumerate(fileList)}
```